# Change font of textbox in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, uwp

my question my sound stupid and there is possibility that something is wrong with my visual studio, but each time I change font of textbox or many other objects, font just stay the same. Does anyone know how to deal with this problem.

Here is an example

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test" PlaceholderText="Website" TextAlignment="DetectFromContent" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
```

No matter what I write in font family section, font stay the same.

Thanks for all your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **[list of fonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/fonts)** that are guaranteed to be available in all Windows 10 editions that support UWP apps:

```
public static string[] FontNames = {
    "Arial", "Calibri", "Cambria", "Cambria Math", "Comic Sans MS", "Courier New",
    "Ebrima", "Gadugi", "Georgia",
    "Javanese Text Regular Fallback font for Javanese script", "Leelawadee UI",
    "Lucida Console", "Malgun Gothic", "Microsoft Himalaya", "Microsoft JhengHei",
    "Microsoft JhengHei UI", "Microsoft New Tai Lue", "Microsoft PhagsPa",
    "Microsoft Tai Le", "Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft YaHei UI",
    "Microsoft Yi Baiti", "Mongolian Baiti", "MV Boli", "Myanmar Text",
    "Nirmala UI", "Segoe MDL2 Assets", "Segoe Print", "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Emoji",
    "Segoe UI Historic", "Segoe UI Symbol", "SimSun", "Times New Roman",
    "Trebuchet MS", "Verdana", "Webdings", "Wingdings", "Yu Gothic",
    "Yu Gothic UI"
};
```

In your case it should be,

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test" PlaceholderText="Website" TextAlignment="DetectFromContent" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
```

If you need any other fonts , add them as resource and use it in application

**[Using Custom Font](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-fonts-in-windows-10-uwp-app/)**

Comment: Thanks, I never thought that Segoe UI Light could be missing from guaranteed fonts.

Comment: If it helps anyone, you can get Segoe UI Light with adding FontWeight="Light.

Comment: You are [missing at least Consolas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/typography#fonts). That may be it from my quick spot-checking, but at least that. Would edit, but wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me maybe try a different font something like Times New Roman

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test"PlaceholderText="Website" TextAlignment="DetectFromContent" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
```

Comment: Thanks will try, I just thought Segoe, should work since it's microsoft font right? Plus I really like Segoe looks.